# FIxed Point Iteration (numerical analysis)

Tags: numerical-methods

The equation $ e^{x} - 4x^{2}=0 $ has a root between 4 and 5.
Fixed point iteration  with iteration function $ \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}} $

---

(A) diverges (B) converges (C) oscillates (D) converges monotonically

---

I know that if we use the fixed point iteration scheme $ x_{n+1}= \phi(x_{n}) $ with iteration function $ \phi(x) $ and $ \phi^{'}(x) \lt 1 $ in the neighbourhood of the solution (which also contain the initial approximation $ x_{0} $ ) then the iterations converge to the solution . for $ \phi(x)= \frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x}{2}} $ , we have $ \phi^{'}(x) \gt 1 $ in the interval $ [4,5] $ so we can't say whether the iterations converge to the solution or not. Then how can we proceed or think of any other way?

Comment: Hint : Study first $x_{n+1}-x_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not possible to "stumble" upon the solution from outside of $[4,5]$, and we know that $|\phi'(x)|>1$ for all $x$ in $[4,5]$, it follows that the iterations will simply diverge.

$\phi'(x)$ essentially represents the behavior of the iterations near the root, with some notable cases:

- Oscillation occurs if $\phi'(x)$ is negative over all values.
- The convergence or divergence is monotone if $\phi'(x)$ is positive over all values.
- Convergence occurs if $|\phi'(x)|<1$ and you can expect to get $|\phi'(x)|$ times closer to the fixed-point on every iteration.
- Divergence occurs if $|\phi'(x)|>1$ and you can expect to get $|\phi'(x)|$ times farther from the fixed-point on every iteration.

The only case where it would be uncertain if this converged or not would be if you had both $|\phi'(x)|<1$ and $|\phi'(x)|>1$ near the root. For this example, this is not the case.